# Redirect url with/without .php extension to index.php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, routes

I use [Shephertz](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/)'s very basic URL routing mechanism to route my page.
However I have come across a problem for file extensions.

If I load `www.example.com/register` I get `index.php`, but keep the URL.

However, if I load up `www.example.com/register.php`, it doesn't send me to `index.php`, but keeps the URL. How come?

This is my `.htaccess` file, which works for non-extensions:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

How can I combine these two?
[I want both of these to be marked blue...](http://regexr.com/3cn1n)

Comment: Do you want to redirect php files (if requested with extensions) to 404?

Comment: isn't `register.php` a real file?

Comment: Yes, yes it is... however, I dont wish to use extensions on files... Only clean URL's.

Comment: You will need to keep your redirect seperate as you cannot redirect and rewrite and the same time.

Comment: @MikeRockett I dont redirect. I want all URL's with php file extensions to go to index.php, without changing the URL.

Comment: That would mean removing the `RewriteCond`, which you don't want as your public-assets will also be filtered through `index.php`. You would probably need to create a seperate rewrite rule above the one you have to state that if the `.php` is present, rewrite to `index.php`. You would also need to make sure that `index.php` checks to see if the `.php` extension is present and only add it if it isn't before requiring the file.

Comment: Take note, however, that this isn't good for SEO purposes as requests to `register` and `register.php` would yield identical content, which search-engines don't like. I would, therefore, suggest a redirect first.

Comment: @MikeRockett `register.php` will redirect to error, while `register` will redirect to the file. I do this by routing. I just want all php extensions and urls without extensions to rewrite to index.php, without changing the URL. Index.php is my primary routing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself by using `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`.
This is what my `.htaccess` looks like now:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I can now redirect all URL's with .php file extension to, a custom 404 page, using [Shephertz](http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/http://)'s routing mechanism.

- www.example.com/example.php  --> 404page.php
- www.example.com/example --> example.php

**This is the 404 page:**

[image]

**This is page without .php file extension**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all external php requests to 404 , You can use the following Rule in .htaccess :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Would love if you helped me out, see question update :)